# Django - Modelform with override password field : initial value not visible (and not saved) in Based UpdateView

Tags: forms, django-views, passwords, updateview

I use a form for handling FTP/SFTP (files) accesses. They can be sometimes updated.
My password field is a Charfield (not required) in my model but I wan't to hide it on updates. I use Bcrypt when saving it.

For this I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531053/3747731) for adding the PasswordInput() widget to my field. I use Crispy so my form in my template is just displayed with `{% crispy form %}`.

```
class FlowStockAutoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FlowStockAuto
        exclude = ['fl_st_auto_report_cross_import', ]
    fl_st_auto_pwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
        label="Password",
        required=False, help_text="BlaBla")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FlowStockAutoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pwd = self.instance.fl_st_auto_pwd
        self.fields['fl_st_auto_pwd'].initial = pwd
```

In [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/), it's recommended to set an initial value with ****init**** (as done above) but when the password widget is active, on my update template, the field remains empty. So if I just wanna update another field, when I save, password is saved blank. It's ok when the Password Widget is off.

I would like it to be prefilled but "blurred" and check when saving if its value has changed.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visibly [almost duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297518/django-passwordinput-is-empty)

had to change from

```
fl_st_auto_pwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
        label="Password",
        required=False, help_text="BlaBla")
```

to

```
    fl_st_auto_pwd = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True))
```

by adding `render_value=True`

I also had to remove

```
label="Password", required=False, help_text="BlaBla"
```

and replace it with

```
self.fields['fl_st_auto_pwd'].label = 'Password'
self.fields['fl_st_auto_pwd'].help_text = 'BlaBla'
```